# Convert Task.Delay to Func<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, func

I have code:

```
private async Task Enqueue(object request)
{
   try
   {
      await _client.Enqueue(request);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      await Task.Delay(_delay);
      await Queue(request);
   }
}
```

I am trying to make this bunch of code more testible, and be able to check this line:
`await Task.Delay(_delay);`

for that I got an idea that I could use Func<>, meaning, that I should pass it to constructor and then I will be able to check what number is passed to delay. Since I am not new to Func usage I was wondering whether it's as easy as I am thinking and all I need is:
        `private readonly Func<int, int> _delayFunc;`

and then:

`await Task.Delay(_delayFunc(_retryDelayMs));`

or whether some `Task` should be returned (like Func<int, Task> etc)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Fun<int>` then would will have to pass the return value of your func to task delay like `await Task.Delay(_fun())`. This enables you to assert in your unit tests whether `_fun` was invoked or not...but not more.

If you wan't to test the daly it would be better to create a `DelaySevice` inject this into your class and use a ([mock](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)) during testing.

something like:

```
interface IDelayService 
{
    Task Delay(int delay);
}
class DelayService : IDelayService 
{
    public async Task Delay(int delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

in your test:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDelayService >();
mock.Setup(x => x.Delay(10)).Returns(()=>Task.Completed);

var target = new YourClass(mock.Object);
await target.Enqueue();

mock.Verify(x => x.Delay(10), Times.Once);
```

Comment: What about `<Func<int, int>` ? then I would pass it like: `await Task.Delay(_delayFunc(_retryDelayMs));` right?

Comment: Or Func<int,Task>?